# Get selected row of inactive datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I have situation that have to know which exact row of datagridview1 (MultiSelect = False) is selected on another (inactive) datagridview1 when I am in some event handler of datagridview2 which is currently active.

I try a bunch of attempts but without correct result.

```
   Private Sub DataGridView2_CellDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, _
           ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
           Handles DataGridView2.CellDoubleClick

   Dim myindex1 As Integer = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex

   OR

   Dim myindex1 As Integer = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
```

None of this don't work like it works when datagridview1 is active and I get index from their event handlers.

What should I do and how accuratelly get selected row of first datagridview from event handler of second datagridview?

EDIT:
Added code:

```
Private Sub datagridview1_RowLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowLeave
    selrow1 = e.RowIndex
End Sub

Private Sub datagridview1_RowPrePaint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowPrePaint
    e.PaintParts = e.PaintParts And Not DataGridViewPaintParts.Focus
End Sub

Private Sub datagridview1_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.GotFocus
    DataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Highlight)
End Sub

Private Sub datagridview1_LostFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.LostFocus
    DataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.InactiveCaption)
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably not the most elegant solution, but you could store the selected row's index as a global variable and then use that index value to access the inactive grid.

Comment: That's what I do now. I take value under DataGridView1_Leave but here is some unreliability in using such solution.

Comment: The code you supplied worked for me. Are the two datagridviews in the same form?

Comment: Yes, as described, datagridview1 and datagridview2.

Comment: What result do you get btw? You say you get the wrong result, but what is the wrong result? Crash? Wrong row number (what result do you get if you select the second row and double click on the other dgv)?

Comment: Wrong result is row 0 (zero) no matter which is selected. Both are binded datagridviews if is important. Besides, I use gotfocus and lostfocus on both to change color to smooth when exits from one. And _RowPrePaint to get rid of cells focus rectangle.

Comment: Can you please add your code for got and lost focus and the _RowPrePaint one. Because this is working fine for me with bindingsource and repainting.

Comment: Added code is same for both datagrids. Public variable which I uses is selrow1 (integer).